# Install libclang on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit machine

Tags: 12.04, clang

I am trying to install libclang on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit. I have gone through some references though I din't get a clear idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 12.04, it is available from [official repositories](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clang). Therefore, to install, type:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

As a reference, whenever I cannot find a package required (particularly libraries), I google `<name> launchpad`, which most of the time gets me to the package which builds the required libraries. [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/) is THE source of information for packages, libraries, versions, ppas, etc. I hope this is of help.

Comment: Thank you, actually I got confused with clang and libclang